# HTML element to be removed and replaced using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a rock, paper, scissors game in Javascript. I have 3 separate images depicting rock, paper and scissors in my HTML and a start button. When I click the start button the `finalDisplay()` function should fire and will set the user and computer points to 0. I have 3 separate functions- `rockFunc()` when the user clicks on the rock image, `paperFunc()` when the user clicks on the paper image and `scissorFunc()` when the user clicks on the scissor image. Each of these functions has a set of conditions. My logic is working exactly as needed but the variable firstDisplay is not getting removed.

```js
const rock = document.getElementById('rock');
const scissor = document.getElementById('scissor');
const paper = document.getElementById('paper');
const start = document.getElementById('start')
const main = document.getElementById('main-container');

var userPoints = 0,computerPoints = 0;



start.addEventListener('click',function(){
    // var userpoints = 0,computerPoints = 0;
    finalDisplay(userPoints,computerPoints,computerChoice);
})

function finalDisplay(userPoints,computerPoints,computerChoice) {
    firstDisplay = document.createElement('div');  
    const text = document.createTextNode(`Computer: ${computerPoints}  User: ${userPoints}`);
    firstDisplay.classList.add('displayinitial');
    firstDisplay.appendChild(text);
    main.appendChild(firstDisplay);
    firstDisplay.after('<h2>Computer chose ' + computerChoice + '</h2>');
    // firstDisplay.remove();
}

 function rockFunc() {
     const choiceList = ['rock','paper','scissor'];
     const computerChoice = choiceList[Math.floor(Math.random()*choiceList.length)];
     if(computerChoice == 'rock' && rock){     
       alert("Play Again");
       firstDisplay.remove();
       finalDisplay(userPoints,computerPoints,computerChoice); 
   
    }
     else if (rock && computerChoice == 'paper') {    
       computerPoints=computerPoints+1;
       firstDisplay.remove(); 
       finalDisplay(userPoints,computerPoints,computerChoice);
   
        
    }

     else if(rock && computerChoice=='scissor'){     
       userPoints=userPoints+1;
       firstDisplay.remove();
       finalDisplay(userPoints,computerPoints,computerChoice);
   
    }
    
 }

 function scissorFunc() {
    const choiceList = ['rock','paper','scissor'];
    const computerChoice = choiceList[Math.floor(Math.random()*choiceList.length)];
    if(computerChoice == 'scissor' && scissor){ 
      alert("Play Again");
      firstDisplay.remove();
      finalDisplay(userPoints,computerPoints,computerChoice); 
          
   }
    else if (scissor && computerChoice == 'rock') {
      computerPoints=computerPoints+1;
      firstDisplay.remove(); 
      finalDisplay(userPoints,computerPoints,computerChoice);
      
       
   }

    else if(scissor && computerChoice=='paper'){ 
      userPoints=userPoints+1;
      firstDisplay.remove();
      finalDisplay(userPoints,computerPoints,computerChoice);
      
   }
   
}

function paperFunc(){
    const choiceList = ['rock','paper','scissor'];
    const computerChoice = choiceList[Math.floor(Math.random()*choiceList.length)];
    if(computerChoice == 'paper' && paper){
      
      alert("Play Again");
      firstDisplay.remove();
      finalDisplay(userPoints,computerPoints,computerChoice); 
          
   }
    else if(paper && computerChoice == 'scissor') {
      computerPoints=computerPoints+1;
      firstDisplay.remove(); 
      finalDisplay(userPoints,computerPoints,computerChoice);
      
       
   }

    else if(paper && computerChoice=='rock'){ 
      userPoints=userPoints+1;
      firstDisplay.remove();
      finalDisplay(userPoints,computerPoints,computerChoice);
      
   }
}

rock.addEventListener('click',function(){
     rockFunc();
 })

scissor.addEventListener('click',function(){
     scissorFunc();
 })

paper.addEventListener('click',function(){
    paperFunc();
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-container{
    min-height: 100vh;

}

.heading-content{
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.heading-content h1{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    word-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: rgb(228, 39, 39);
}

.main-content{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 30px;
}

.button{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:15px;
}

.button button{
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    /* width: 90px; */
}

.game{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 10px 15px 40px rgb(58, 58, 58);
}

.displayinitial{
    text-align: center;
    margin:50px;
    word-spacing: 20px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rock,Paper,Scissors</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/rock-paper-scissors/styles.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-container" id="main-container">
        <div class="heading-content">
            <h1>Rock, Paper, Scissors Game!</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="button">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="start">Start</button>


        </div>

        <div class="main-content" id="main-content">

            <img src="/rock-paper-scissors/images/rock.png" alt="rock" class="game" id="rock">
            <img src="/rock-paper-scissors/images/scissor.png" alt="Scissors" class="game" id="scissor">
            <img src="/rock-paper-scissors/images/paper.png" alt="paper" class="game" id="paper">


        </div>




    </div>

    <script src="/rock-paper-scissors/script.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Now your firstDisplay variable is local inside the finalDisplay function.
For accessing firstDisplay from other function inizialize the var outside of the function

```
var firstDisplay;
```

then assign it in finalDisplay()

```
firstDisplay = document.createElement('div');
```

then delete the node in others functions:

```
firstDisplay.remove();
```

Comment: I've made changes as you've mentioned above but then my logic is not correct and I am not sure why. I added another function to display to the user what the computer is choosing each time. But unfortunately, the logic seems to be incorrect and I am not sure of the reason behind it. I tried using if-else-if statements and switch case but still doesn't work. Could you please state the reason behind this.

Comment: In js if you initialize variables inside a function they are stored locally, and you cannot use them outside of the function. To create a global variable you have to initialize it outside of the function: then you can also use and change his value into a function.
A good practice is to init all var at the beginning of the script. 
To better undertand i suggest you this resource: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp